# USACO Computing Problems - Could not find or load main ride

Tags: java

I am trying out codes in the USACO Computing Olympiad and got stuck with the first problem. If I submit the below code, I get the following error :

> Run 1: Execution error: Your program exited with exit status `1'.

```
    ------ Data for Run 1 [length=14 bytes] ------
    COMETQ 
    HVNGAT 
    ----------------------------

      Your program printed data to stderr.  Here is the data:
      -------------------
      Error:_Could_not_find_or_load_main_class_ride


      -------------------
```

Code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Ride {
    public static BufferedReader bReader;
    public static PrintWriter out;
    public static StringTokenizer st;

    public static void initializeSys(String fileName) throws IOException {
        bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName + ".in"));
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName + ".out")));
}
    public static long findSumOfLetters(String value) {
        long prod = 1;
        if (!value.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
                prod = prod * (long) (value.charAt(i) - 64);
            }
        }
        return prod;
    }
    public static void yourRideIsHere() throws IOException {
            String x = null;
            long[] prods = new long[2];
            Arrays.fill(prods, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                st = new StringTokenizer(bReader.readLine());
                x = (String)st.nextElement();
                prods[i] = findSumOfLetters(x.toUpperCase());
            }
            if (prods[0] % 47 == prods[1] % 47) {
                out.print("GO");
            } else {
                out.print("STAY");
            }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        initializeSys("ride");  
        yourRideIsHere();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Please help me find out where I go wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't used the USACO website before but I'm guessing you have a text box to enter the code and a separate field where you can enter the name of the class.  Is this correct?  If so, are you entering the class name in this field as `Ride` or `ride`?

Comment: No, I just need to select the file. With a comment above the code, which I have missed to mention . It goes like this :

/*
ID: yourUSACOid
LANG: JAVA
PROG: ride
*/

where the prog name "ride" is already given by the problem statement.

Comment: Yeah, it did work! I changed the class name to "ride" and it accepted the solution. Thank you Luke Woodward :-)

Comment: I pulled my hair out for this damn thing.Finally got answer thankyou

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, the solution was to change the class name to `ride` instead of `Ride`.

Comment: Possibilities: it's a typo. Typo questions should be closed, not answered. Also the site hates online judge questions in general (because they tend to be low quality).